# Cannot call Connection.commit in distributed transaction

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, jta, xa

I am using Weblogic 12c and I am getting the below error while committing distributed transactions in my application.

"java.sql.SQLException: Cannot call Connection.commit in distributed transaction.  Transaction Manager will commit the resource manager when the distributed transaction is committed"

The part of code throwing exception is:

```
Session sessionNew = HibernateService.getService().getSession();
sessionNew.connection().commit();
```

This question has been asked several times, but the solution I am seeking is different.
The most common solution is to disable XA transactions to resolve the issue.
But my application contains more than resources like database, JMS etc.
Can anyone please suggest a solution other than the one mentioned above.

Also, I needed to understand if there is any relation between JTA transaction timeout value and the above-mentioned error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you really need XA transactions you must let the transaction manager commits or rollbacks the transactions. Your code should not explicitly call commit or rollback.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin, Thank you. if I remove the second line, it shouldn't affect the application by any chance? and is there any relation between the above error and JTA transaction timeout value?

Comment: there is no relation between the error message and the JTA timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if you switch @TransactionManagement (TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) to @TransactionManagement (TransactionManagementType.BEAN) this error will no longer occur.

So you define what you define when you commit, not the server.